# IPhone TableView not Populating JSON Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a page that contains a tableview - and a textfield and button that sends a zip code to a PHP page and returns JSON data. I am not able to populate the table view with the returned data. The NSLog shows the data is being returned, but the table remains blank. No errors.
Code:

```
- (IBAction) searchzip: (id) sender
{
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"zip=%@", zipField.text];
NSString *hostString =     @"https://www.mysite.com/searchzip.php?";

// Append string and add percent escapes
hostString = [[hostString stringByAppendingString:post] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *hostURL = [NSURL URLWithString:hostString];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:hostURL];
self.zipArray = [jsonString JSONValue]; 
NSLog(@"%@", zipArray);
[jsonString release];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section    {
return [zipArray count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [self.zipArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
static NSString *Prospects = @"agencyname";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Prospects];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:Prospects]   autorelease];
}

// setting the text
cell.text = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"agencyname"];    
self.navigationItem.title = @"Zip Search";

// Set up the cell
return cell;

}
```

Header File:

```
@interface SearchZipViewController : UITableViewController{
NSMutableArray *zipArray;
IBOutlet UITextField *zipField;
IBOutlet UIButton *searchButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *zipArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *zipField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *searchButton;
- (IBAction) searchzip: (id) sender;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the basic issue is that you are trying to build a composite view (textfield, button and tableview) and use a `UITableViewController` as the controller.  It's been cited here on SO and elsewhere that this is basically a no-go.  Instead, try something like:

```
@interface SearchZipViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UIButton* searchButton;
    IBOutlet UITextField* zipField;
    IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;
}

@end
```

then wire the `UITableView` in IB to the `tableView` ivar in the File's Owner -- it appears from your comments about that you were attempting to wire the table view element in the composite view to the File's Owner, a `UIViewController` -- not what you want.

Comment: OK, I fixed the tableView by adding an IBOutlet to my header. But still no data. I am pointing tableView to the table view. Where exactly should I put the [tableView reloadData]; as stated. I am still getting no data displayed.

Comment: Well, as sosborn indicated, I'd put it at the end of the `searchzip` method.  I'd put a breakpoint there, and then also one in each of the tableview delegate methods.  Make sure that the TV delegate methods are firing after the `reloadData` method is called.  In particular, step through the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to make sure you actually have valid data for a given row.  Alternatively, at this point you should at least have `NSLog` statements in that method to ensure you really have the data you think you have.

Comment: Also, it looks like you are using `SBJSON`?  You are *sure* you have an array of objects -- i.e., "[{},{},{}]" not something else?  Measure twice, cut once :)

Comment: Yeah, running NSLog(cell); is not returning anything... I have an NSLog(@"%@", zipArray); and it returns the JSON correctly but its in ({}{}) format

Comment: okay -- if you put a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you initialize the variable `infoDictionary` what is its value? Is it a valid object?

Comment: setting a breakpoint at NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [self.zipArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; didnt even trigger the debugger.

Comment: okay -- double-check -- in your NIB did you wire the `dataSource` and the `delegate` of the table view to the File's Owner?

Comment: The delegate actually wasnt wired to the Files Owner, but no change when i did. Still no action on the breakpoint.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6176/discussion-between-savagenoob-and-jstevenco)

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your search zip method you should add this line:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Otherwise your tableView has no way of knowing that you have new data to show.

Comment: hm, I did that and still nothing. On my editor i have the UITableView's dataSource and delegate pointing to Files Owner is this right?

Comment: Yeah, that should be right. Does cellForRow actually get called when the view loads? Does [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"agencyname"] return what you expect?

Comment: Yeah, its getting data correctly. This has something to do with my editor setup. I have the view setup as a table view, but with a textfield and a button, with a table view at the bottom. Under Files Owner I have view pointed to TableView. On other pages that auto loads JSON into a table view I have tableView pointed to the table view. If I do this on this page it erases the text field and the button....

Comment: basically the issue i think is that I tableView which actually populates the data is not showing up on my outlets in my Files Owner. I just dont know how to fix it.

Comment: So you added a tableView to a UITableViewController? yeah, if you do that you might run into problems. Try inheriting from UIViewController rather than UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `cell.textLabel.text` to set the text of your table cell. The `text` property is deprecated.

Also, try setting a breakpoint on that line to make sure the local variables you have there actually have the values you'd expect (i.e. the correct JSON values). Maybe you have a typo in one of your key strings (like the casing)?